# Proof verification: if $f$ is a solution of $(y')^2+y^2=1$ that is defined over $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ attains at least one of $1,-1$ as a value.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

**Context**: I'd like to prove that for any pair of numbers $(x_0,y_0)$ with $|y_0|\leq 1$, the initial value problem

$$(y')^2+y^2=1,y(x_0)=y_0$$

will have infinitely many solutions that are defined over $\mathbb{R}$. In my analysis of the differential equation, I've determined that it locally has exactly two solutions when $|y_0|<1$, each a sine wave, and that these "branch off", so to speak, to infinitely many when their graphs reach $\pm 1$. Since I'm interested in solutions defined over $\mathbb{R}$, I can prove the infinitude of solutions by showing that any $\mathbb R$-defined solution attains either $1$ or $-1$ as a value.

> **Problem**: if $f$ is a $\mathbb R$-defined solution of $(y')^2+y^2=1$, is it true that $f(x_0)=1$ or $f(x_0)=-1$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb R$?

I've been thinking about this problem for a while now, and believe I have conceived of an argument that proves the answer is yes. Here it is:

**Proof**: suppose, for the sake of finding a contradiction, that $f$ is a $\mathbb R$-defined solution of $(y')^2+y^2=1$ that never attains $1$ nor $-1$ as a value. Since the differential equation implies that $f$ must satisfy $-1\leq f(x)\leq 1$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$, it follows from our assumption that $-1<f(x)<1$ for every $x$, or $\left|f(x)\right|<1$.

Note that the ODE is equivalent to $|y'|=\sqrt{1-y^2}$, so $\left|f(x)\right|<1$ and the fact that $\sqrt{1-t^2}>0$ when $|t|<1$ implies that $|f'(x)|>0$ for every $x$. This yields the following result:

> **Result 1**: For any $x$, either $f'(x)>0$ or $f'(x)<0$.

For what follows, we'll need to strengthen Result $1$ to the following:

> **Result 2**: $f'$ is either strictly positive or strictly negative.
>
> *Proof*: From Result $1$, we have that either $f'(0)>0$ or $f'(0)<0$. Suppose $f'(0)>0$ and pick any $x_1\neq 0$. From Result $1$, it follows that either $f'(x_1)>0$ or $f'(x_1)<0$.
>
> Notice that it is not possible for $f'(x_1)<0$ to be true because [Darboux's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) would then imply that $f'(c)=0$ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x_1$, contradicting Result $1$. Thus, $f'(x_1)>0$; since $x_1$ was arbitrary, this proves that $f'$ is strictly positive.
>
> The argument for $f'(0)<0$ is pretty much identical, so it is omitted. Thus, $f'$ is either strictly positive or strictly negative.

With this established, it follows that either

$$f'(x)=\sqrt{1-[f(x)]^2}\text{ for every }x\text{, or }f'(x)=-\sqrt{1-[f(x)]^2}\text{ for every }x$$

or, because $\sqrt{1-[f(x)]^2}>0$,

$$\frac{f'(t)}{\sqrt{1-[f(t)]^2}}=1\text{ for every }t\text{, or }\frac{f'(t)}{\sqrt{1-[f(t)]^2}}=-1\text{ for every }t$$

Integrating each case from $x_0$ to $x$, using $\int 1/\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\sin^{-1}(x)$, and rearranging, we get

$$f(x)=\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)+x-x_0\right)\text{ for every }x$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$f(x)=\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)-(x-x_0)\right)\text{ for every }x$$

If the correct expression for $f$ is the first one, then we can evaluate it at $\frac{\pi}{2}+x_0-\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}+x_0-\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)$. This is justified because the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x_0-\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)\right) &= \sin\left(\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}+x_0-\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)-x_0\right)\\
&= \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
&= 1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}+x_0-\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)\right) &= \sin\left(\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}+x_0-\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)-x_0\right)\\
&= \sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
&= -1
\end{align}

This contradicts the assumption that $f$ never attains $1$ nor $-1$. We can reach a contradiction from the second expression too; just evaluate $f$ at $\frac{\pi}{2}+x_0\color{red}{+}\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)$ and $-\frac{\pi}{2}+x_0\color{red}{+}\sin^{-1}\left(f(x_0)\right)$ instead. Thus, our original assumption must be false, so any $\mathbb R$-defined solution always attains at least one of $1,-1$ as a value. $\blacksquare$

I appreciate any and all feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I shall assume the solution is $C^2$. Then differentiate $y'^2+y^2=1$, we get $2y'(y''+y)=0$.

If $y\not=\pm 1$ for all $x$, then $y'\not=0$ for all $x$. Therefore $y''+y=0$ which has general solution $y = A\sin(x+B)$, and using the original equation, we have $A^2=1$, so $A=\pm 1$, and hence $y=\sin(x+B)$ (as $A=-1$ can be obtained by choosing a suitable $B$), for which both $1$ and $-1$ can be attained, a contradiction.

Comment: Actually, I can prove that either $y\equiv 1$ or $y\equiv -1$ or $y$ can attain both $1$ and $-1$. This is slightly harder, and after I saw  your correction, I edited the answer to fit the problem, as this is more clear.

Comment: We can probably do better than $C^2$, but it's a bit annoying, as without $C^2$, we could connect $y=\sin(x)$ with $y=1$ at e.g. $x=\pi/2$ to get some piecewisely defined $C^1$ solutins, but even for this kind of solution, it's still true that both $1$ and $-1$ can be obtained. Anyway, the current version of the problem has the cleanest answer.